# Blockchain on top of a blockchain

Tags: blockchain

1) Is it possible to build another blockchain on top of the Ethereum blockchain?

2) Is making a token on the Ethereum blockchain considered making a another blockchain on top of the Ethereum blockchain?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A blockchain, at least according to the Wikipedia definition, is data. It is something you store, not something you build (although it can, I suppose, be "constructed" in the same sense you can construct a stack or a queue). Since you can store arbitrary data on the Ethereum blockchain, you could *store* another blockchain on top of the Ethereum blockchain. Also, since the Ethereum virtual machine allows inputs, outputs, and persistent storage, you could, in fact, implement a smart contract that allows you to interact with said blockchain via the Ethereum blockchain.

No; tokens (at least none that exist to my knowledge) on the Ethereum blockchain do not even remotely meet the Wikipedia definition of a blockchain so I believe it is safe to say they are not considered to be blockchains; they are secured *by* the Ethereum blockchain. On the other hand, I believe payment channels could be considered blockchains (although they are only checkpointed on other blockchains and/or brought back "on-chain" at specific times).

Answer (score 0):

Blockchain on blockchain, you are making a task tedious one :-)

- Now every new blockchain has got their own genesis block , so if
  somehow you make your genesis block on Etherum blockchain you are
  good to go.
- That is exactly what is done during forking but it is something that
  breaks the fundamentals of what blockchain are build on i.e
  immutability although you can do it but not recommended.